# How to validate name

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to validate name in form. Name may be such as:

```
Knop
knop
knop-Doe
knop doe
Knop Doe Bald
Knop-Doe-Bald
```

And I have problem with spaces. In form I have:

```
forms.RegexField(regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$', max_length=36, required=True)
```

But this won't work.

How to do it?

Comment: What doesn't work? Valid names aren't validated? Invalid names get passed? You get an exception? OS error? Your hard disk crashes? Monitor blows up? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is matching lowercase letters `a-z`, upper case letters `A-Z`, digits `0-9`, underscores `_`, dots `.` and hyphens `-`.

It is not matching spaces, so names like *Knop Doe Bald* will not match.

Try including a space in your regular expression

```
r'[a-zA-Z0-9_. -]+$'
```

Note the space goes before the hyphen, not after, otherwise the hyphen will be interpreted as a range.